# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, cors

This is my CORSConfig class

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CORSConfig{

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS")
                        .allowedHeaders("*")
                        .allowCredentials(false)
                        .maxAge(3600);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This Bean I have define in SecurityConfig.java

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .cors(httpSecurityCorsConfigurer ->
                    httpSecurityCorsConfigurer.configurationSource(request ->
                                    new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues()))
            .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                    auth.requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            );

    http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    return http.build();
}
```

I am using spring boot 3.1.6, spring-security 6.1.5 with JDK 17. Above configuration I have used to handle CORS. This is working fine when I test the API from Postman and Swagger on **server**.

But when I intergrate react.js in frontend then GET, POST methods are working fine but for PUT method this is giving *No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource* error.

I have try the answers of old question regarding this on stackoverflow and also try with Google. Also coordinate with my teammates but no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `applyPermitDefaultValues`, so only the defaults are set, see [`CorsConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfiguration.html#applyPermitDefaultValues()):

> **applyPermitDefaultValues**
>
> `public CorsConfiguration applyPermitDefaultValues()`
>
> By default `CorsConfiguration` does not permit any cross-origin requests and must be configured explicitly. Use this method to switch to defaults that permit all cross-origin requests for GET, HEAD, and POST, but not overriding any values that have already been set.
> The following defaults are applied for values that are not set:
>
> - Allow all origins with the special value "*" defined in the CORS spec. This is set only if neither origins nor originPatterns are already set.
> - Allow "simple" methods GET, HEAD and POST.
> - Allow all headers.
> - Set max age to 1800 seconds (30 minutes).

You have to configure your custom `CorsConfiguration` accordingly.

See also [CORS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.1/servlet/integrations/cors.html).